# Android - dynamically add images to list using array

Tags: java, android, arrays, local-storage

I have several string arrays stored in my database that contain file names. I want to loop through this array to return the files one by one that are stored in the internal storage. Example of one of the array:

```
[["12","21","31"],["empty","22","32"],["13","23","33"]]// this is the array unmodified
```

Below is the code I have now but just gives me an index error as the index is 12 at the start because of the array begins at 12.

```
layout = layout.replaceAll("\"empty\",?", "").replaceAll("[\"\\]\\ 
 [\"]+","").replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");  //this removes the "empty" string
    String[] layoutArray = layout.split(",");


    int rows = 3;
    int columns = 3;

    int layoutElement = 0;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                // get the image from the internal storage
                int imageIndex = Integer.valueOf(layoutArray[layoutElement]) - 1;
                String imageFile = layoutArray[imageIndex];
                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(getFilesDir(), imageFile).getAbsoluteFile().toString());
                mImageList.add(new Grid(getApplicationContext(), i, j, image, imageFile));
                layoutElement++;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I know the code I have is completely wrong in logic but I need help with this and can't get my head around it. each of the array values has a file name stored by that number, I removed "empty" because it is not needed. My end goal is to place these files(that are images) into a grid view.

Comment: paste error log

Comment: @Mohammad java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are splitting the text using "," which splits the array - that you provided as example - into 9 element ... you need to replace all "],[" with something like "]-[" and split the string using "-" .

  ```
  layout = layout.replaceAll("\\] , \\[", "\\] - \\[");  
  String[] layoutArray = layout.split("-");
  ```
- You are incrementing the value of `layoutElement` for each nested loop without resetting it in the first loop >>
  this code should work as expected

  ```
  layout = layout.replaceAll("\"empty\",?", "").replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").replaceAll("\\],\\[", "\\]-\\[");
      String[] layoutArray = layout.split("-");

  try {
      for (int i = 0; i < layoutArray.length; i++) {
          layoutArray[i]= layoutArray[i].replaceAll("[\\[\"\\]]","");
          String[] splitted = layoutArray[i].split(",");
          for (int j = 0; j < splitted.length; j++) {
              int imageIndex = Integer.valueOf(splitted[j]) - 1;
              String imageFile = splitted[imageIndex];
              Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(new File(getFilesDir(), imageFile).getAbsoluteFile().toString());
              mImageList.add(new Grid(getApplicationContext(), i, j, image, imageFile));

          }
      }
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank for the reply! I tried your solution but now I get the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=8; index=11

Comment: I've included another problem in the answer which could cause this issue

Comment: there is 8 just for this array after removing the "empty" string with regex. the files im trying to retrieve are all under the name of each element. So "12" has a file in internal storage named "12"

Comment: Yes same error. for some reason the index is using the actual value of the element giving length = 1 and index = 12

Comment: stop the code that deletes empty from the array and run again

Comment: and edit the question with full string array not the modified one ..  make a copy from your program

Comment: The array I have is the unmodified one, I removed all the brackets and parenthesis to get the int value on its own

Comment: print the unmodified version and paste it to the question

Comment: Still saying same error :( though your code is good and I don't know why its doing that

Comment: I got it to work! at String imageFile = splitted[imageIndex]; I just replaced ImageIndex with 'j'. Thank you for the help!